# Formik - How do I control the value of another input field automatically when one field changes?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm using Formik's `useFormik` hook to manage my forms in ReactJS. But I don't know how to build a custom onChange handler that works on top of or alongside Formik's `handleChange` function. I tried building a custom change handler like below but I'm unable to figure out what step to take next.

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

function testForm() {

  const { handleChange, values } = useFormik({
    initialValues: { title: ``, slug: `` },
    onSubmit: ( values ) => console.log( values  )
  })
  
  const customHandleChange = e => {

    // let's suppose title field changed.
    const { value } = e.target;

    // I can do other functions here, like fetching data from API
    store.dispatch( getUserByTitle( value ))

    // But I'm trying to set a custom value for the slug field automatically depending on changing title field value
    let slugValue = value.toLowerCase()
    
    // handleChange function changes the value of title input. How do I also change slug input?
    handleChange(e)
  }

  return (

    <div>

      <input type="text"
             name="Title"
             value={ values.title }
             onChange={ customHandleChange }/>

      <input type="text"
             name="slug"
             value={ values.slug }
             onChange={ handleChange } />
    </div>

  )

}
```

I tried setting value of the slug input directly as follows.

```
 <input type="text"
        name="slug"
        value={ values.title.toLowerCase() }
        onChange={ handleChange } />
```

But if I do that, I won't be able to type in the field and make a change as the value is strictly set from the title input. Users should also be able to change the slug field value to whatever they want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [setFieldValue](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void):

```
function testForm() {
  const { handleChange, values, setFieldValue } = useFormik({
    initialValues: { title: ``, slug: `` },
    onSubmit: ( values ) => console.log( values  )
  })
  
  const customHandleChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;

    setFieldValue('title', value);
    setFieldValue('slug', value.toLowerCase());
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text"
              name="Title"
              value={ values.title }
              onChange={ customHandleChange }/>
      <input type="text"
              name="slug"
              value={ values.slug }
              onChange={ handleChange } />
    </div>
  )
}
```